# porting python tree builder to C++

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

I am trying to port a TreeBuilder python class to C++, keeping the structure as close as possible to the original. Here is a simplified python version: https://onlinegdb.com/I4dg0hCtg

- The purpose of tree is to represent a generic game tree (Chess, Go, Checkers, etc.) It is passed forward to a class (Whatever), which builds an another representation based on some depth-wise statistics.
- Environment here is a mock class, in the real application actions are passed back based on the game's rules
- The main reason of porting the code is speed. I am very new to C++, but as I know dynamic allocation on the heap costs more. I do not know if it worth (or even possible) to build such a tree without dynamic initialization.
- As far as I know using raw pointers has a little benefit of performance over smart pointers, but GC should be done by hand. My plan is after the trees are generated, and used by Whatever class (see my first point), Whatever class has to destroy the tree's node recursively. (Node's destructor should delete its children)

*main.cc*

```cpp
#include "Node.h"
#include "Environment.h"
#include "Options.h"
#include "TreeBuilder.h"

int main() {
    Node* node = new Node();
    Environment* environment = new Environment();
    node->environment = environment;
    Options* options = new Options();
    options->root = node;

    TreeBuilder* treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    Node* tree = treeBuilder->buildTree(options);

    tree->printTree();
    return 0;
}
```

*Node.h*

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// Environment and Node has circular dependency, forward declaration
class Environment;

class Node
{
public:
  Node * parent = nullptr;
  int depth = 0;
  std::vector < Node * >children;
  Environment *environment = nullptr;

  void printTree (); // only for debugging
};
```

*Node.cc*

```cpp
    Node::~Node() {
        for (Node* child : children) {
            delete child;
        }
    }
```

*Environment.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "Node.h"

class Environment
{
public:
  std::vector < int >getActions (Node * parent);
};
```

*Environment.cc*

```cpp
#include "Environment.h"

std::vector<int> Environment::getActions(Node* parent) {
    std::vector<int> actions;
    if (parent->depth != 3) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= parent->depth; x++) {
            actions.push_back(x * 100);
        }
    }
    return actions;
}
```

*Options.h*

```
#pragma once

#include "Node.h"
#include "Environment.h"

class Options
{
public:
  Node * root = nullptr;
  Environment *environment = nullptr;
};
```

*TreeBuilder.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "Node.h"
#include "Environment.h"
#include "Options.h"

class TreeBuilder
{
public:
  Environment * environment = nullptr;
  std::vector < Node * >getChildren (Node * parent);
  void _buildTree (Node * node);
  Node *buildTree (Options * options);
};
```

*TreeBuilder.cc*

```cpp
#include "TreeBuilder.h"
#include <iostream>

std::vector < Node * >TreeBuilder::getChildren (Node * parent)
{
  std::vector < Node * >children;
  std::vector < int >
    actions = this->environment->getActions (parent);

  for (int x = 0; x < actions.size (); x++)
    {
      Node* node = new Node ();
      node->parent = parent;
      node->depth = parent->depth + 1;
      node->environment = parent->environment;
      children.push_back (node);
    }
  return children;
}

void
TreeBuilder::_buildTree (Node * node)
{
  std::vector < Node * >children = this->getChildren (node);
  node->children = children;
  for (int i = 0; i < children.size (); i++)
    {
      this->_buildTree (children[i]);
    }
}

Node* TreeBuilder::buildTree (Options * options)
{
  Node *root = new Node ();
  root->environment = options->root->environment;
  this->environment = root->environment;
  this->_buildTree (root);
  return root;
}
```

Here is a playground version https://onlinegdb.com/wN1BRN8Yu to see it in action.

Is there a way to improve this code? Any constructive criticism or advice is more than welcome!

Comment: Reviews are offtopic here. There is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Make sure to read their rules to make the question on topic there

Comment: I posted this question to codereview.stackexchange.com, but they said "This question is possibly off-topic because it seems too theoretical."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This question is cross posted. It was asked on code review several hours ago. It is missing context and does not follow the guidelines.

Comment: On the code review version, it is obvious that Node.cc is not complete one of the functions is missing the definition. Node.h and Node.cc do not compile on compilers that follow the standards.

Comment: @pacmaninbw updated he code and the link to the online playground where it compiles and runs without error (C++ 17)

Comment: now I am confused. THis is your question there https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284429/port-node-and-treebuilder-from-python-to-c. Its not closed and it received an answer (well ok 55 mins ago). Please do not post the same question on different platforms. I cannot see where someone said it would be "too theoretical".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is already posted here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284429/port-node-and-treebuilder-from-python-to-c and already has an answer